# Cannot receive parse.com push notification from devices

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I've successfully integrated Parse.com to android app & i can receive the push notification from Data browser and send the notification from android to ios ok.

When i tried to send the notification from ios to android, android cannot receive in my customize **MyPushReceiver**.

Installation on Parse is written with **deviceToken**.

I'm using Parse v1.10.2

Here is manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".push.MyPushReceiver"
    android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.mypackage" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is code in Application:

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_ID);
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("global", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            }
        }
    });
ParseInstallation currentInstallation =         ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            }
        }
    });
```

Help me!

Comment: check your Parse dashboard panel..

Comment: a row is written but Pushes Sent is 0